# PLY Lex: ID could be anything

Tags: python, lex, ply

I have a following simple format:

```
BLOCK ID {
    SUBBLOCK ID {
        SUBSUBBLOCK ID {
            SOME STATEMENTS;
        };
    };
};
```

I configured ply to work with this format. But the issue is that ID could be any string including "BLOCK", "SUBBLOCK", etc.
In the lexer I define ID as:

```
@TOKEN(r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*')
def t_ID(self, t):
    t.type = self.keyword_map.get(t.value, "ID")
    return t
```

But it means that BLOCK word will not be allowed as a block name.

How I can overcome this issue?

Comment: why wouldnt BLOCK word be allowed as BLOCK name(what do you even mean by that?)? all you have done is define what a token is

Comment: It ID (block's, subblock's or any other block) could be any string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a non-terminal `name` to be used instead of `ID` in productions which need a name, such as `block : BLOCK name braced_statements`:

```py
    # Docstring is added later
    def p_name(self, p):
        p[0] = p[1]
```

Then you compute the productions for `name` and assign them to `p_name`'s docstring by executing this before you generate the parser:

```py
Parser.p_name.__doc__ = '\n| '.join(
         ['name : ID']
         + list(Lexer.keyword_map.values())
)
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable. But how I use it in my "p_nameprods" function?

Comment: I editted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I probably dont understand your question

but i think something like the following would work (its been a long time since
I messed with PLY so keep in mind this is pseudocode

```
FUNCTION_ARGS = zeroOrMore(lazy('STATEMENT'),sep=',')
FUNCTION_CALL = t_ID + lparen + FUNCTION_ARGS + rparen
STATEMENT= FUNCTION_CALL | t_Literal | t_ID
SUBBLOCK = Literal('SUBBLOCK') + t_ID + lbrace + STATEMENT + rbrace
BLOCK = Literal('BLOCK') + lbrace + oneOrMore(SUBBLOCK) + rbrace
```

Comment: This was a very basic example. My full spec is much more complicated. I'm looking ways to allow names be any string.

Comment: names can be any string ...

Comment: I wish. If I use my example, it complains on word "BLOCK" as an ID.